# Pre-populated association for nested form rendered empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

My PlanList `has_many :items`.

I want my plan_list#new to have a nested form, where I can pre-populate items.

I tried

```
# View
<%= form_for @plan_list do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :items do |item| %>
    <%= item.text_field :quantity %>
  <% end %>
```

with

```
  # Controller
  def new
    @plan_list = PlanList.new
    @plan_list.items.build(quantity:1)
    @plan_list.items.build(quantity:2)
  end
```

However I only see empty inputs for items.

I also tried `<%= f.fields_for @plan_list.items do |item| %>` but it will only show one item (the last one with quantity 2). How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: What do you want to show instead of empty inputs for items?

Comment: I want to show, like the two quantities I have built in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items`.

I thought I could add this later when I implement the create method, but it is essential for both **form creation** and **attribute mass assignment**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the build method of associations as:

```
  def new
    @plan_list = PlanList.new
    @plan_list.items << @plan_list.items.build(quantity:1)
    @plan_list.items << @plan_list.items.build(quantity:2)
  end
```

Comment: Nope doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is must and should resolve the issue accepts_nested_attributes_for :items

```
  <%= form_for @plan_list do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :items do |item| %>
      <%= item.text_field :quantity %>
    <% end %>


  def new
    @plan_list = PlanList.new
    @plan_list.items.build(quantity:1)
    @plan_list.items.build(quantity:2)
  end
```